# Как обойтись без goto в php?

Tags: php, goto

[image: goto stone age]

Есть ли какая-то уловка/хитрость обходиться без функции goto? Дело в том, что мне нужно сделать бесконечный цикл для выполнения функции, и кроме goto я пока что ни до чего не додумался.

Comment: нужен пример цикла...... и описание что делается и что хочется получить..... зависит от задачи...... в 99% случаев никто не использует goto..... если вы их часто используете - значит хромает логика

Comment: А чем `while(true)` не подходит?

Comment: Точно. Спасибо. Я до такого не додумался

Comment: @Ezdrael так оно все заест при таком цикле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бесконечный цикл создать в php можно, но в большинстве случаев вы можете получить ошибку. В первых двух случаях вы скорее всего получите ошибку (т.к. в настройках `php.ini` по умолчанию выставлено 30 сек. и бесконечно `php` крутить код не будет). В последнем примере код будет работать 20 сек и просто остановится.

Пример использования цикла **while**:

```
<?php
while(true){
echo 'Этот текст будет показан бесконечное число раз';
}
```

Пример использования цикла **for**:

```
   <?php
    for(;;){
    echo 'Этот текст будет показан бесконечное число раз';
    }
```

Пример использования цикла **for** c "остановкой на 20й секунде":

```
   <?php
    $current_time=time();
    for(;;){
    echo 'Этот текст будет показан 20 секунд';
    if(time()>$current_time+20)break;
    }
```

Comment: Домо аригато 